# Geany opening not related files

Tags: geany

I am using Geany editor for my programming . It is junk "Files" and "bin" along with the requested file which is very annoying.

I tried uninstall and reinstalling geany but same issue persists.
[image]

Comment: Wich command you run to have this situation?

Comment: @freezed I have to just open any file via Winscp  in geany and these two files are opened by default

Comment: sorry I cannot try on a windows env.